# Load testing of a web page and generating data in SQL Database

Tags: testing, sql-server-2008-r2, load

I have a page,and at a time more than 1000 of entries to this form has to be made.
For Ex: multiple users accessing this form will be entering data in single form from different locations.So,This scenario has to be generated to test the load of same form.

Manually generating this data in database is tedious,so is there any query to enter data in database using SQL Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache JMeter.

> Apache JMeter is an Apache project that can be used as a load testing
>   tool for analyzing and measuring the performance of a variety of
>   services, with a focus on web applications.

https://jmeter.apache.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can write a PHP/CURL load agent on RedLine.  Here is a pointer to the documentation and sample code to do that - https://www.redline13.com/blog/writing-a-custom-load-test/.  This is what we did for our big load test on RunSignUp when we had to simulate 50,000 users each filling in their own registration.